# How to restrict access via CloudFront URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a static page hosted on AWS S3, how can I block off access via the CloudFront URL and only grant access via the S3 URL

Comment: Oh! So you wish to prevent CloudFront in general from accessing a particular Amazon S3 bucket? This is indeed a strange requirement. Could you provide some details of _why_ you wish to achieve this, and whether you are wanting to block only your _own_ CloudFront, or anyone else's CloudFront? (If you provide more details, we might be able to provide a better answer.) Feel free to edit your Question to provide more details.

Answer (score -1):

It is a strange requirement as for security you may like to block the access to S3 and only allow access to cloudfront. But you may have some reasons for it.

You can use the whitelist/blacklist feature of the cloudfront to allow or block certain IPs. You can provide the signed URLs to grant the access to S3.

Comment: so I need to blacklist the CloudFront url?

Comment: you can blacklist/whitelist IPs in cloudfront distribution settings

Comment: This is not a good approach. Instead, use an Origin Access Identity, which was designed specifically for this purpose.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein The requirement in the question is not to restrict the S3 access but the other way around, to restrict the access from CloudFront. Yes the requirement is strange as it is best practice to restrict the S3 direct access.